# Using static variables in Open CL?

Tags: opencl

Can we use `static` variables within the `openCL` kernel.
I tried to use it but got the following exception

```
 ptxas application ptx input, line 11; error   : Module-scoped variables in .local state space are not allowed with ABI ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
```

## EDIT

I found a page that says its not supported. So how can we make a variable to retain its old value during multiple calls?

Comment: If you want a variable to maintain the value between different kernel runs, simply use a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenCL 1.2, all program scope variables must be in the `__constant` address space (see Section 6.5, page 224 of the specification), which means that you cannot have this kind of variable that can be both read and written by multiple kernels. Instead, you need to create a buffer object that you pass in as an argument to each kernel that needs it (it will retain its contents across multiple kernel calls).

In OpenCL 2.0, program scope variables in the `__global` address space are allowed, so when we have hardware and implementations for OpenCL 2.0 you will be able to do this sort of thing much more easily.